# Unrecognized Selector in AVplayer setNumberOfLoops Method

Tags: objective-c, loops, avplayer

When calling the numberOfLoops method like so:
`[_player setNumberOfLoops:-1];`

I get the following error:
`-[AVPlayer setNumberOfLoops:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7d52d30`

How can this be fixed?

Code:

Header:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

}


@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *player;

- (IBAction)playMusic:(id)sender;


@end
```

Implementation:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)playMusic:(id)sender {
    _player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://urlpath.wav"]];
    [_player setNumberOfLoops:-1];
    [_player prepareToPlay];
    [_player play];
}

@end
```

Thank you for your time,

Yoni201.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AVPlayer` doesn't have a `numberOfLoops` property. That is a property of `AVAudioPlayer. Don't ignore compiler warnings when you build your app.

Also, you defined `_player` to be an `AVAudioPlayer` but you alloc/init `AVPlayer`.

Change your code to:

```
NSError *error = nil;
AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://urlpath.wav"] error:&error];
if (player) {
    [player setNumberOfLoops:-1];
    [player prepareToPlay];
    [player play];
    self.player = player;
} else {
    NSLog(@"Error create audio player: %@", error);
}
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't notice that. Thank you so much!

Comment: Also, why does XCode correct "player" to "_player" even though my AVAudioPlayer defined in my header file is named "player" ?

Comment: You have a property named `player`. The synthesized ivar is named `_player`. Your code really should be `self.player = [AVAudioPlayer...`. If you were not using ARC your code would have bad memory issues by directly accessing the ivar instead of the property.

Comment: This is what the `error` parameter is for. Instead of passing `nil`, pass a valid error pointer. Check if the result is `nil`. If it's `nil`, then log the error.

Comment: Thank you! Looks like the error is: (OSStatus error -43.) It looks like AVAudioPlayer doesn't support streaming via HTTP. Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: Download the URL into an `NSData` and use the `initWithData:error:` method. Of course you should do the data access in the background.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30192/discussion-between-yoni201-and-rmaddy)

Comment: How would I do this in the background? I assume you don't mean call any methods while my app is running in the background, like before the app loads?

Answer (score 2):

You've created an instance of `AVPlayer`, not an instance of `AVAudioPlayer`. It looks like you want to be creating an `AVAudioPlayer` instead (as is indicated by your choice of that class for the actual `player` property on your class. `AVAudioPlayer` actually has the `numberOfLoops` property, while `AVPlayer` does not. For more information, see the documentation for [AVAudioPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008067) and [AVPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009530).

Comment: Yeah it's weird I didn't notice it, Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I think that the method you are calling doesn't exist (acceosing to your error).

Try: _player.numberOfLoops=-1

Comment: My class is being instantiated with this code:
_player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://urlpath.wav"]];

Comment: I changed [_player setNumberOfLoops:-1]; to _player.numberOfLoops = -1;
Same error :( It's weird because xcode auto-complete lets me select setNumberOfLoops as a method meaning it has to be a method.

Comment: The dot syntax is just syntactic sugar and is replaced with Objective-C message passing by the compiler. Changing from message passing to the dot syntax or back will never be the answer to any issue.

Comment: The difference was that one was a method accessing the property and the other was actually changing the property, no?